# How to save previous values in fragment while we switch to other fragment and return to last one

Tags: android, android-fragments, listadapter

I have a fragment (say **FragA**) gets and another fragment (say **FragB**).

In **FragA** I set some values `seekbar` and put a check on `checkbox`

but now if click on **FragB** and then click on **FragA** then all set values are gone.

For fragments I have used a `ListAdapter` which set a fragment depending on position no. where I clicked. I don't want it on back button press but on clicking that `fragment`.

**My Question is how can I restore a fragment to its previous state while setting parameter in other fragments and clicking to those fragments which I set before.**

Comment: have you tried onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: yah!! it always return null.

Comment: @sahilsolanki How did you get to fix this please?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of onSaveInstanceState(), below is the example how you need to implement it

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}
```

And later you can use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }
```

}

It will be a good idea if you go through [fragments documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can  save each transaction to a back stack managed by the activity, allowing the user to navigate backward through the `fragment` changes (similar to navigating backward through activities).

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Before you call `commit()`, however, you might want to call `addToBackStack()`, in order to add the transaction to a back stack of fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back button.

[detail](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)